# How to generate 5h-isochrones?

Tags: qgis, isochrone

I'm very new ot the GIS world, but I suddenly need to generate isochrones from several points with time ranges up to 5 hours. I managed to use QGIS and the ORS plugin to generate nice isochrones, but ORS refuses to compute over the 1-hour isochrone. Is there a way to get past that limit, or can another tool do what I want ? If possible I would like to script it so that whenever I need to do it, I just have to supply a list of coordinates.

Comment: are you bound to a certain programming language if you say you would like to script?

Comment: @Leo No. My goal is to generate a shapefile with those isochrones for later use in an R program. I can use anything before that.

Comment: so maybe this would be useful?: https://geoffboeing.com/2017/08/isochrone-maps-osmnx-python/

Comment: @Leo Thanks for the link, this will definitely be useful to me later, but it looks like it doesn't work for this project. It appears to me like OSMnx takes into account street length, but not max allowed speed on said street, so there's no way to specify that a highway is faster than a regular street (though I'd be happy to be corrected on this)

Comment: did you try all of them?: https://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/drive%20time%20isochrones/

Comment: or this one: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/addons/v.isochrones.html

Comment: @Leo Thanks for the continued help ! I did find these methods (QNEAT3 and GRASS) but I wasn't able to use them because they both seem to require that I download a "road layer" and I was unable to find a suitable data source. I tried downloading the OSM Europe map from http://download.geofabrik.de/ but QGIS doesn't seem to be able to open it (~20GB so not too surprising). I'd be fine if the file only contained France though, so if you know how I could get my hands on that it could work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103035/discussion-between-pierre-cathe-and-leo).

Comment: If you work out a solution, please post it as an answer. I think it will be quite helpful to others with a similar question.